# Sending message to the user with the custom properties like people who have registered through email

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

Now I need to send the message to the people:
 That we custom their properties.For example whether the email is activated after they register,if they have activated the email then they can receive the notification but the inactivated one cant,we set the properties when the user login their account ,if the first one who has already activated their Email ,then if we send the notification that with that receiver who activated email tab ,then the phone can receive notification .and then we changed the account that haven't activated the email,then send the same notification ,and then the phone still can receive the notification ,and also if we send the message in a not activated email tab ,the phone cant receive the notification.

I want to the the reason of this problem and the ways of solve it . 
Thank you for your help.

Edit:
if someone have registered through some specific key like email which will be stored in my database...i could send notifications to them..!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   - Pls Follow this Documentation before asking a query

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ try this link